# Как автоматизировать git push?

Tags: git, git-push

Есть ли способ автоматизации заливки кода в репозиторий с помощью `git push`?

Comment: А что именно подразумевается под "автоматизацией" git push'a ?

Comment: @Gab.Vad До `git push` делаеться `git commit`, Вы именно какую автоматизацию хотите?

Comment: @Gab.Vad тоесть `git commit` делаете в ручную да? и после этого надо `push` ? есть способ создание консольной команды которое сделает обе команды друг после друга, когда вызовешь созданную команду.

Comment: по хорошему, нужно добавить git push  в post-commit хук. Жестоко, но задачу сделает.

Comment: Если задуматься, всплывёт много "если". Скажем, что будет, **если** push будет отклонён?

Comment: естественно. Но пуш можно всегда попробовать сделать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 6):

если под «автоматизировать» подразумевается «объединить *commit* и *push* в одну команду», то можно сделать такой, например, псевдоним (*alias*) под названием `cp` (или под любым другим, не конфликтующим с существующими командами, понимаемыми программой *git*):

```
$ git config alias.cp '!f(){ git commit && git push; }; f'
```

и вызывать так:

```
$ git cp
```

как понятно из содержимого, при этом будут выполнены последовательно команды:

```
$ git commit
$ git push
```

причём вторая будет выполнена только при условии успешного завершения первой.

---

понятно, что в приведённом псевдониме можно добавлять какие-нибудь опции к командам. например, часто используют опцию `-a` команды `commit`:

```
$ git config alias.cp '!f(){ git commit -a && git push; }; f'
```

---

если хочется, чтобы псевдоним работал не только в текущем хранилище, но и во всех остальных, надо добавить опцию `--global` при его создании/модификации:

```
$ git config --global ...
```

---

чтобы удалить этот псевдоним, используйте опцию `--undef`:

```
$ git config --undef alias.cp
```

а если он был описан глобально, то и опцию `--global`:

```
$ git config --global --undef alias.cp
```

Comment: `git commit -a -s` уж ещё полезнее ;)

Comment: почему не написано просто `git config alias.cp 'git commit && git push'`? зачем нужна функция оболочки? — а просто на тот случай, если вы по ошибке добавили к `git cp` какие-нибудь опции/параметры: функция их просто «съест», а без неё эти опции/параметры «попадут» команде `git push`, что может иметь нежелательные последствия. так что функция — (нелишняя) страховка от ошибки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin отличный трюк с функцией, возьму на вооружение!