# Как в Git задать автоматическое нажатие на удаленный репозиторий после фиксации

Tags: git, git-push

Работаю в Git на ОС Windows с помощью Git Bash. Необходимо, чтобы в удаленный репозиторий автоматически нажимались изменения после фиксации (commit), ну или один раз в сутки по определенному расписанию. При выполнении Push пароль не запрашивается (SSH), реализовано с помощью SSH-агента. В папку локального репозитория .git\hooks был добавлен файл post-commit.sample (содержимое меняла несколько раз):

1.

```
`#!/bin/sh 
git push origin master`
```

2.

```
`#!/usr/bin/env bash
 branch_name=`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` 
 retcode=$?
 non_push_suffix="_local"
 # Only push if branch_name was found (my be empty if in detached head state)
 if [ $retcode = 0 ] ; then
 #Only push if branch_name does not end with the non-push suffix
 if [[ $branch_name != *$non_push_suffix ]] ; then
 echo
 echo "**** Pushing current branch $branch_name to origin [i4h_mobiles post-     commit hook]"
 echo
 git push origin $branch_name;
 fi
 fi`
```

3.

```
`#!/bin/sh
 usage()
 {
 cat << EOF
 usage $0 [<options>] [-r <remoterepo>]
 Will add a post-commit function in the git repo which will automatically push
 to the default or remote repo.
 OPTIONS:
 -o Overwrite any existing post-commit hook
 -r Remote repo
 -a pushes all branches
 EOF
 }
 params="$@"
 OVERWRITE=0
 ALL=""
 while getopts  "hor:a" OPTION
 do
 case $OPTION in
 h)
 usage
 exit 1
 ;;
 o)
 OVERWRITE=1
 ;;
 r)
 REMOTEREPO="$OPTARG"
 ;;
 a)
 ALL="--all"
 ;;
 esac
 done
 shift $(( $OPTIND - 1 ))
 HOOKS_FOLDER=.git/hooks
 POST_COMMIT=$HOOKS_FOLDER/post-commit
 if [ -d $HOOKS_FOLDER ]; then
 if [ -f $POST_COMMIT ] && [ $OVERWRITE -eq 0 ]; then
 echo "Post commit hook already exits, please add 'git push' manually in   .git/hooks/post-commit"
 exit 1
 fi
 if [ $OVERWRITE -eq 1 ]; then
 mv $POST_COMMIT "$POST_COMMIT.bak"
 echo "moved old hook to $POST_COMMIT.bak"
 fi
 echo "git push $REMOTEREPO $ALL" > $POST_COMMIT
 chmod 755 $POST_COMMIT
 REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename "$PWD")
 echo "added auto commit to $REPOSITORY_BASENAME"
 exit 0
 else
 echo "This command must be run in the root of a Git repository."
 exit 1
 fi`
```

Ни одна из этих вариаций файла не помогла...
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что надо выполнить для автоматизации?

Comment: Неужели сочетания "нажатие на репозиторий" и "нажимать изменения" не кажутся вам уродливыми?

Comment: Кажутся, просто думала так будет понятнее. Искала информацию в Интернет, там используют именно такую терминалогию

Comment: Вот какой замечательный способ я нашла: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672901/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-git-push?rq=1
Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Уберите `.sample` из названия файла и дайте ему права на выполнение.

Comment: А какое у него тогда должно быть расширение? Просто у меня в этой папке все файлы с расширением .sample
А как ему дать права на выполнение?

Comment: Никакого. Sample это "образец".

Comment: Убрала расширение в файле post-commit
Попробовала все 3 варианта. Всё равно не выполняет автоматически push после того, как я выполнила команду commit...